# if isset $_POST output fail

Tags: php, isset

I'm trying to create a banning system for a chat that I made and it has a separate "console" only seen by admins. Im using Mac OS 10.11.4, I am the owner and am using Mamp with php version 5.6.10

Ban.php

```
    <?php

    $ban = $_POST['ban'];
    $mybfile = fopen("banned.txt", 'a');
    $txtb = ($ban." , ");

    //Makes sure ip banned it not an admins
    if (isset($_POST['ban'])) {
        //example ip addresses
        if ($ban === '1.1.1.1' || 192.168.1.132) {
            echo 'Can\'t ban an Admin';
        } else {
            echo 'IP banned';
            fwrite($mybfile, $txtb);
            fclose($mybfile);
        }
    }

    ?>

    <style>

        .ban {
        background-color: black;
        width:30em;
        height:5em;
        color: #7ACC52;
        }

        .buttonBAN {
        border:1px solid black;
        width: 85px;
        height: 55px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
    <form method="POST">
        BanCMD<br />
        <input type="text" name="ban" class="ban">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="buttonBAN">
    </form>
    </body>
```

Chat.php:

```
   <?php

    require "blocked.php";
    require "connect.inc.php";
    require "core.inc.php";
    require "commands.php";

    $sent = $_POST['chat'];
    $myfile = fopen("chat.txt", 'a') or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = ($sent."\n");
    $first = getuserfield('username');
    $active = ($first.":".$ip_addr);
    $activef = fopen("ip-user.txt", 'a');
    $myFile = "domains/domain_list.txt";

    if (loggedin()) {
        echo 'Welcome, '.$first,'<br />';
            if ($first != 'SnR' || 'Koi') {
                fwrite($activef, $active."\n"."=");
            }
        } else if (!loggedin()) {
            die('Not logged in');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['chat'])) {
        if (!empty($sent)) {
            fwrite($myfile, $first.': '.$txt.'=');
            fclose($myfile);
        } else if (empty($sent)) {
            echo 'Cant send an empty message','<br />';
        }
    }

    $file = "chat.txt";
    $linecount = 0;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($handle)){
      $line = fgets($handle);
      $linecount++;
    }

    fclose($handle);

    if ($linecount > 49) {
        unlink($file);
    } else {
        echo 'Line count: '.$linecount,'<br />';
    }

    echo 'Chat will reset at 50 lines','<br />';
    echo 'Your IP:';
    echo $ip_addr,'<br />';

    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- <a href='active.txt'>Online users</a><br /> -->
            <iframe id='reload' src='refresh.php'>
               <fieldset class="field">
                        <div id="list"><p><?php
                            $filename = 'chat.txt';
                            $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

                            $detain = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

                            $chat_array = explode('=', $detain);

                            foreach($chat_array as $chat) {
                              echo $chat.'<br />';
                            }
                       ?></p></div>
              </fieldset>
          </iframe>
          <form action="chat.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="chat" class="textbox">
              <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button">
          </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php

        if ($first == 'SnR' && 'Koi') {
            include 'AdminCMD.php';
            include 'ban.php';

    ?>

            <iframe id='reload' src='refresh2.php' class="field2">
                <fieldset class="field">
                </fieldset>
            </iframe>

    <?php
        }

    ?>
```

The problem is that everything is fine until you give an input, no matter what you put into the box the output is always "Can't ban an Admin" meaning that it doesn't write to the given file

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `($ban === '1.1.1.1')` change if like this. Does it make difference?

Comment: No it doesn't make a difference

Comment: `var_dump ($_POST)` at the very beginning. What do you have for 'ban'?

Comment: I put `var_dump ($_POST);` at the very beginning and got `array(0) { }`

Comment: and after and input of anything i got `array(1) { ["ban"]=> string(7) "45.45.45.45" } Can't ban an Admin`

Comment: and for 'ban' that is the class of the input box, that was my understanding of isset and @_POST, if that is wrong please correct me

Comment: There is something else you are not sharing. The form without action set will refer to the same file.. are the html and php snippets in the same file?. I copied paste your code and it works as is.

Comment: yes they are in he same file and the only thing i haven't mentioned is that that code is included to another page but i did as you did made a new file and copied paste the code and it still doesn't work

Comment: could it be my php version? i'm using 5.6.10

Comment: Can't see anything related to php version. Tested your code all in one file and it worked as is. Please modify your question with complete scripts.

Comment: that is hundreds of lines but okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains an error, preventing the file from being written. The first line of PHP code,`$ban = $_POST['ban'];`, could fail if no post data was sent. You need to first check if the `$_POST['ban']` was set. A fixed version of your code can be found below.

```
<?php

    //Makes sure ip banned it not an admins
    if (isset($_POST['ban'])) {
        $ban = $_POST['ban'];
        $mybfile = fopen("banned.txt", 'a');
        $txtb = ($ban." , ");
        if ($ban === '1.1.1.1') {
            echo 'Can\'t ban an Admin';
        } else {
            echo 'IP banned';
            fwrite($mybfile, $txtb);
            fclose($mybfile);
        }
    }

?>

<style>

    .ban {
        background-color: black;
        width:30em;
        height:5em;
        color: #7ACC52;
    }

    .buttonBAN {
        border:1px solid black;
        width: 85px;
        height: 55px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        BanCMD<br />
        <input type="text" name="ban" class="ban">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="buttonBAN">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: still has the same problem

Comment: @janeboe I ran the code locally on my machine with no issues, there must be something wrong with your PHP setup. Do you have write permissions to the location where the file will be saved?

Comment: yes i am the admin/owner of the computer(Mac OS 10.11.4) and am using php version 5.6.10

Comment: @janeboe Using my updated code, what does running `var_dump($ban);` print out? Be sure to insert it after `$ban = $_POST['ban'];`

Comment: the output is `NULL` @Flibio

Comment: @janeboe That output is impossible if you are using my updated file. Are you absolutely sure that you have copied and pasted my file I included in my answer?

Comment: okay nvm i did it wrong at first, when i put your code by itself it worked thank you. but when i included it to the page its supposed to be on(chat.php, i attached the code in my original question) it changes to null

Answer (score 0):

When i ran your code it returns **undefined index** `ban`, you can try this and make sure what is not working for you.

```
   <?php
    $ban = isset($_POST['ban']) ? $_POST['ban'] : null;
    $mybfile = fopen("banned.txt", 'a');
    $txtb = ($ban." , ");

    //Makes sure ip banned it not an admins
    if(isset($ban)){
    if ($ban === '1.1.1.1') {
                echo 'Can\'t ban an Admin';
            } else {
                echo 'IP banned';
                fwrite($mybfile, $txtb);
                fclose($mybfile);
            }
    }
    ?>

   <style>

    .ban {
    background-color: black;
    width:30em;
    height:5em;
    color: #7ACC52;
    }

    .buttonBAN {
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 85px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    }

</style>

<body>
<form method="POST">
    BanCMD<br />
    <input type="text" name="ban" class="ban">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="buttonBAN">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: that fixed the undefined index but still having the same problem